# Sort list index by value

Tags: c#, list, sorting, indexing

I have a list in C#

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8);
```

And I would like to make a list of items in `temp` that satisfy a bool expression, such as

```
List<int> results = temp.Sort(x > 2);
```

But .Sort() doesn't exist. The  resulting list `results` would then contain

```
(3, 4, 6)
```

Which are the ***indexes*** of the values in the original list `temp` that are greater than 2.

Sorry if this is trivial or has been asked before; I'm new to coding and to SO. Thanks!

EDIT: As some of you have correctly pointed out, I'm don't actually want to *sort* the list, I just want to filter it. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like *sorting* to me at all. It looks like *projecting* and *filtering*...

Comment: which is why the OP said 'bool expression, such as'. He wasn't saying it exists and doesn't work. @Jon, this isn't aimed at you but to the person who commented and removed it.

Comment: Rather than adding an "EDIT" section, why not just rephrase your question so it is clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output it appears that **you need Indices**

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8};
var newList = temp.Select((r, i) => new { Index = i, Value = r })
                    .Where(r => r.Value > 2) //For your condition
                    .OrderBy(r => r.Value)
                    .Select(r => r.Index)   //For output
                    .ToList();
```

This would return you `(3, 4, 6)`

EDIT: Since the question has been edited and pointed out that sorting the list based on value is not required, in that case `OrderBy` in the above statement can be left out.

```
var newList = temp.Select((r, i) => new { Index = i, Value = r })
                    .Where(r => r.Value > 2) //For your condition
                    .Select(r => r.Index)   //For output
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think you need the OrderBy. Even though the questioner talks about "sorting", they don't seem to mean it.

Comment: @billpg, I would leave it for the OP, if sorting is not required than OP can leave out that out.

Answer (score 2):

A simple, fast and easy to understand solution would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
    if(temp[i] > 2) results.Add(i);
```

Comment: But... but... there's no LINQ in this answer! :)

Comment: @billpg I love LINQ but sometimes it just makes it more complicated to solve a very simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make a list of items in temp that satisfy a bool expression,

That would be [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8);

List<int> results = temp.Where(x => x > 2);
```

There are many variations of `Select` and `Where` that include the index of items that meet a criteria - if you can be more clear on what you *want* then you will get better examples.

Comment: "Which are the indexes of the values in the original list" - your answer doesn't cover this.

Comment: It's unclear (to me anyways) if that's what the _desired_ output is or if that's the _current_ output.

Comment: I think the OP's update to their question, plus the other answers makes things a lot clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
List<int> results = temp.Select((x, index) => new { Index = index, Number = x })
                        .Where(x=>x.Number > 2)
                        .Select(x=>x.Index);
```

Comment: The questioner wanted the indexes of those items greater than 2.

Comment: @billpg and Daniel Kelley please see my updated post. Thanks.

Comment: @Christos use linqPad or VS to check your syntax, instead of directly writing here.

Comment: @I4V do I have made any error? Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @I4V I just corrected one error I found, a missing `)`. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep store the index before applying the where clause, or it will be lost.

```
List<int> temp = new List<int>{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 8 };
List<int> results = temp.Select((x,i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
                        .Where(x => x.Value > 2)
                        .Select(x => x.Index)
                        .ToList();
```